# What does ORDER BY 5 DESC mean?

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-order-by

```
SELECT Departamentos.Nome_Dep,  
       Funcionarios.Nome AS Funcionario,
       Funcionarios.Salario,
       AVG(Funcionarios.Salario) OVER(PARTITION BY Departamentos.Nome_Dep) "Média por Departamento"
       Salario - AVG(Funcionarios.Salario) OVER(PARTITION BY Departamentos.Nome_Dep) "Diferença de Salário"   FROM Funcionarios
INNER JOIN Departamentos
    ON Funcionarios.ID_Dep = Departamentos.ID
ORDER BY 5 DESC
```

The Order By 5 is throwing me off. I've never anything like it. Order By [colunmname] yes, but Order By [number], never seen before. I pulled this off an article.

Note: This is T-SQL.

Source: [Window Functions in SQL Server 2005, 2008, 2012](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/window-functions-in-sql-server/)

Comment: NOte that this is normally not a good practice as someone could easily add a column and change the ordering without noticing, I suspect it is done in this case however because column 5 is calculated column and they didn't want to go to the trouble of repeating the calulation in the ordering.  BTW there is a missing comma between columns 4 and 5

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This will order by the 5th field in this SELECT statement

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. I immediately saw it in the article after looking at your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Order by the 5th column in the result set.

Answer (score 4):

The number represents the index of the column within your select list.

Source: http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/05/quick_tip_order_by_1_descendin.html

Answer (score 4):

Order by fifth column in the result set descending.

Answer (score 2):

It is the **SORTING BY RELATIVE POSITION**.

You can use the SQL ORDER BY clause to sort by relative position in the result set, where the first field in the result set is 1. The next field is 2, and so on.
Here in this case Order by 5th field in the result set.

Go through http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/order_by.php 
     about sql order by.

Answer (score 1):

Useful when a similar column name has become a calcuated output field,

In the following example, it would be confusing if say 'order by numberofVioation' as this column name has just become the name of a query output SUM field (of the same old column data)

So it become useful in calculated output field

Example:

Original fields:

name|    Type|      RiskLevel|      Date|      results|          violations|

/* now add an extra Sum of Violation for each type, pls note 'order by 2 desc' refers to order by the 2nd queried column, ie hi to low */

select Type, sum(numberOfViolations) as numberOfViolations
from restaurantsTable 
group by Type 
order by 2 desc

Answer (score 0):

Order by 5th field in the result set.